# Query params not persisting in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, query-string, ember-query-params

Given the template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#link-to 'test' (query-params test=0)}}link{{/link-to}}
</script>
```

and the script

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('test');
});

App.TestController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['test'],
  test: null
});
```

The query params are not showing up in the url when I click, shown here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qawoza/1/edit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're looking at it in editor mode in jsbin, the output is in it's own iframe.  If you pop out to live preview you'll see your query params.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qasilu/1